# Can I increase the in-call volume of my microphone?

Tags: calls, volume-control, microphone, sony-xperia-active

I have a Sony Xperia Active which is barely 2 months old and its in-call mic volume is really low. Is there any way I can increase the volume?

Comment: I think that is either a hardware or  a firmware issue. Have you tried recording with the mic? Is it loud and clear?
If it is a firmware issue, report it to Sony. And if Hardware related problem, use a headset, or change your device.

Comment: Sorry, this is a really old question. I don't even have that phone anymore :-|

Comment: Oops.. i didn't see that coming.